# How to get the compiled file path with hashed of worker.js loaded from worker loader

Tags: reactjs, typescript, babel-loader, worker-loader

I have a typescript react application which is using babel and webpack for compilation
I have written a rule to load my worker with

```
config.module.rules.unshift({
      test: /gif\.worker\.js$/,
      use: {
        loader: 'worker-loader',
        options: {
          filename: 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].js',
          publicPath: '/',
        },
      },
    });
```

now I wanted to get the output path of this worker in my typescript code to create a worker instance

I am using gif.js.optimized which require worker path to create workers

```
const gif = new GIF({
      workers: 2,
      quality: 10,
      height: height,
      width: width,
      workerScript: workerPath,
    });
```

the worker path should be something like [baseurl]/static/js/gif.worker.[hash].js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of worker-loader just used as file loader and its working fine

```
{
  test: /gif\.worker\.js)$/,
  use: {
    loader: require.resolve('file-loader'),
    options: {
      name: 'static/js/[name].[contenthash:8].[ext]',
    },
  },
}
```